# Updating state variable without changing the value of other states assigned to them on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating this countdown app  where it should display a random word and then start the timer.
Timer works fine but the real problem is when I uncomment the line where the new word is updated in the state.

Since the state is changed, the component re-renders. Again the state is changed causing it to rerender and so on going into an infinite loop of updating the word. I'm not getting how to solve this in an optimal way.

**EDIT: The new word generation process should repeat after timer hits zero.**

```js
function App() {
  const [newWord, setNewWord] = React.useState('Default');
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(6);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // setNewWord(generateWord())
    let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('time reduced to ', time);
            if (time > 0) {
                setTime(time - 1);
            }
            if (time === 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                // exitGame();
            }
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        };
  })
  
  // Generate a new word
  function generateWord() {
    let words = ['yeah', 'lol', 'gotcha']
        let randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
        return words[randIndex];
    }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div> Word = {newWord} </div>
      <div> Time = {time} </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `generateWord` and pass the result as the initial state:

```js
function App() {
  const [newWord, setNewWord] = React.useState(generateWord());
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(6);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('time reduced to ', time);
            if (time > 0) {
                setTime(time - 1);
            }
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        };
  }, [time])
  
   React.useEffect(() => {
    if (time === 0) {
      // exitGame(); ?
      setNewWord(generateWord())
      setTime(6)
    }
  }, [time])
  
  // Generate a new word
  function generateWord() {
    let words = ['yeah', 'lol', 'gotcha']
        let randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
        return words[randIndex];
    }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div> Word = {newWord} </div>
      <div> Time = {time} </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: But what if I need to repeat the process after the timer hits zero ?

Comment: Maybe replace setInterval with setTimeout?

Comment: The way I'm building the project makes more sense with setInterval with some modifications in the timer code. But I agree that the implementation I provided here should have used setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

Set the work's `useEffect()` dependencies to an empty array, so it won't be called after initial re-render. Move the `exitGame` logic to another `useEffect()`.

```js
function App() {
  const intervalId = React.useRef();
  const [newWord, setNewWord] = React.useState('Default');
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(6);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setNewWord(generateWord())
    intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(time => time > 0 ? time - 1 : time);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    };
  }, [])
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(time);
    if (time === 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalId.current);
      // exitGame();
    }
  })

  // Generate a new word
  function generateWord() {
    let words = ['yeah', 'lol', 'gotcha']
    let randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    return words[randIndex];
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div> Word = {newWord} </div>
      <div> Time = {time} </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: But then it makes sense to add the "time" state as a dependency to the clearInterval effect or?

Comment: You can eschew the dependency array, or add one with time if you want to be stricter.